# Is 'mind you' a question tag?

Tags: question-tags

> “That plate is hot, **mind**.” (Angela Downing, English Grammar)

Prof. Angela says ‘mind’ above is a question tag. 
Is ‘mind you’ below the same tag?

> "Don't know why he's so bothered," said Ron. "If I'd brought a toad
>   I'd lose it as quick as I could. **Mind you**, I brought Scabbers, so
>   I can't talk."
>  (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

Comment: *Mind* in the first example is not a question tag. It's an imperative instruction to *mind yourself* or *mind the plate* -- to take care about yourself/it. *Mind you* is included in [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/mind-you) and is whatever the opposite of an *intensifier* is.

Comment: "Prof. Angela says ‘mind’ above is a question tag." Care to cite a reference? It's *not* a question tag AFAIK.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"*Mind you*" is **not** the question "*do you mind?*". It is just a shortened form of "*keep X in mind*". And of course, in the first example, "*mind*" is just a shortened form of "*mind you*".

> **mind you**
> a phrase introducing something that should be taken into consideration.
>
> -- [TheFreeDictionary.com](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/mind+you)

So your examples:

> That plate is hot, **mind**.
>
> **Mind you**, I brought Scabbers, so I can't talk.

are equivalent to

> That plat is hot; **keep that in mind**.
>
> **Keep in mind**, I brought Scabbers, so I can't talk.

Comment: No, *mind* in the first example is definitely not *mind you*, as Andrew Leach noted on the question. My own view is that it converts a statement into a warning. But I agree with your analysis of the second example, which is much commoner.

Comment: @TimLymington I see your point, and I agree that is a warning. FWIW I have heard the phrase *mind you* used that way before (US English) -- "*That plate is hot, mind you*" / "*Mind you, that plate is hot*". So I'm not sure what the difference is other than tone.

Answer (score 3):

One subset of the words / strings often known as 'sentence connectors' (this subset also considered a subset of pragmatic markers involving both information ordering and speaker viewpoint) includes:

**however**; **however, on reflection**; **mind you**; **still**; **nonetheless**; **nevertheless**; **all the same**

All these words / strings are used to present two contrasting ideas. *Mind you*, *however, on reflection*, and *still* have a hint of reconsideration by the speaker to concede the alternative viewpoint – an afterthought. The others indicate a more planned statement of contrast (and are more formal).

Examples:

> Smoking is proved to be dangerous to the health. Nonetheless, 40% of
>   the population smoke.
>
> Our teacher promised to take us on a field trip. However, he changed
>   his mind last week.
>
> Peter was warned not to invest all of his savings in the stock market.
>   Nevertheless, he invested and lost everything.
>
> You should not shirk your civic responsibility to vote. Mind you, I
>   haven’t.

**Mind** in the sense used here means 'bear / keep this in mind' or, more urgently, 'mind out for / that', as stated above. It is a pragmatic marker, of the attention-focusing variety.

Comment: +1 A tasty new term - whose is it?

Comment: @StoneyB : sorry, which term!?

Comment: Sorry - 'sentence connector'

Comment: @StoneyB: There's a good overview, with links to sub-'classes', by Kenneth Beare at http://esl.about.com/od/writingintermediate/a/w_connectors.htm . Just looking up "sentence connector" on Google gives quite a few relevant articles. Sadly, the usual terminological difficulties surface, based largely on whether 'still' and 'mind you', say, should have identical or different analyses.